# iOS: block ads in Apps without Jailbreak and VPN tunnel (normal 3G/4G network)

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, ios-appstore, adblock

For example in [RT app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rt-news-russia-today/id649316948?mt=8) there are annoying ads. There is no way to pay subscription without ads.

Howto block ads in Apps (in Mobile Safari I block them all)? I found only apps that offer a VPN tunnel (you need 100% to trust them) and solutions for iPhones with Jailbreak. Are there other possibilities?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because apps aren't able to inject themselves into other apps without jailbreaking, they are only able to use Safari Content Blockers in Safari or routing network traffic through a VPN.